# How to populate object with findById? CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have MongoDB collections with post objects. The last one

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9fd72e6ec9ee294aec4ef1"), "comments" : [ "{\n  _id: 5f9fd72e6ec9ee294aec4ef0,\n  postedBy: 5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1,\n  body: 'These were the days!',\n  __v: 0\n}" ], "title" : "Vou comer voce! ", "body" : "What a wonderful life!", "postedBy" : ObjectId("5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-02T09:53:50.652Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

I want to add new commment.
I tried this way.

```
  async function addComment() {
    try {
      const mycomment = await Comment.create({
        postedBy : mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1'),
        body: 'Here comes the new one!'
      });
      const post = await Post.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f9fd72e6ec9ee294aec4ef1')).populate('comments');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

PostSchema

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  comments: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }] 
});
```

Comments Schema

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  title: String,
  body: String,
});
```

Error in terminal

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{\n' +
  '  _id: 5f9fd72e6ec9ee294aec4ef0,\n' +
  '  postedBy: 5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1,\n' +
  "  body: 'These were the days!',\n" +
  '  __v: 0\n' +
  '}" at path "_id" for model "Comment"
```

Complete outout can be found [here](https://controlc.com/a2800fda)

How to add commments by using post _id?

Comment: Why the type is String in comments: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }] and not mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ?

Comment: can you give us the Comment's schema ?

Comment: @BinaryMan I added my Comments schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from

```
comments: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }]
```

It should be:

```
comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
      }]
```

Comment: No,it does not help.

Comment: Why the type is String in comments: [{ type: String, ref: 'Comment', }] and not mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ?

Comment: Typo,I changed that,but still I got the message. I will try to copy and paste the link.

Comment: @RichardRublev please try this: 
const mycomment = await Comment.create({
        postedBy : '5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1',
        body: 'Here comes the new one!'
      });

Comment: Thaat is comment,but comment should be added to my Post.

Comment: OK! so your question is how to add your comment, after creation of it, to the post ? that's it ?

Comment: Yes,I have many users,that all add many comments to my Post(blogpost). May be something is wrong with my model in the first place?

Comment: no, your models are all good, just do comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
      }]  as i suggested to you, than, after creating the comment, get back its id and add it to the comments array of ids in the associated post.

Comment: I will try,let you know.

Comment: you can also add the post id into the comment model:
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
post: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'}
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  title: String,
  body: String,
});